# Generate a date based on Month and year column

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to generate a date based on users Month and year,
I would need a resultant table to have 2 column a startdate and enddate as supposed to having from month, tomonth and year.
Please see the table structure shown in example and resultant table formatting.

```
example:
co1         col2        col3
fromMonth   toMonth     year
5           12          2012
1           4           2013


result:
co1         col2    
StartDate   EndDate 
01/05/2012  31/12/2012  
01/01/2013  30/04/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use DATEFROMPARTS and pass the month & year columns

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to know how can I incorporate this when copying data from one table to another

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (fromMonth  INT, toMonth   INT,  year INT)
INSERT @tbl VALUES
(5           ,12          ,2012),
(1           ,4          ,2013)

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, (YEAR - 1900) * 12 + fromMonth - 1, '1900-01-01') StartDate
        , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, (YEAR - 1900) * 12 + toMonth, '1900-01-01')) EndDate
FROM    @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

For start date :

```
CAST(CAST(1 AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(col1 AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(col3 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
```

For end date:

```
CAST(CAST(31 AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(col2 AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(col3 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
```

I hope this helps you.